# Plotting multiple features in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, data-visualization

I have 74 features in my Data Frame, and I want to plot them v/s the target column. How do I do that using subplots in Matplotlib?

Comment: What is the type of your columns ? What is the type of the target column ? Have you tried something ?

Comment: @Adrien numerical and categorical, and i have mapped the categorical data. I tried looping but i could not come up with a code, have u coded anyth like this before?